# Stand up ML instance using Cloud Formation Template

Tags: marklogic

I would like to standup single node ML instance based on latest AMI,
using Cloud Formation Template.

I found following page but, I could not see single node template with
latest ML version.
http://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws

Which template should I use? and is their any good guide to
modify the existing template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the mlcluster cloud formation templates (mlcluster-vpc.template or   mlcluster.template) from https://developer.marklogic.com/products/cloud/aws and specify number of zones as 1 and hosts in zones as 1.

That will create a single node MarkLogic node in the region that you have chosen.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, I have an additional question. I see 9.0-9.3 specified as version in the template, but MarkLogic download page provides 9.0-9.1. Is this means AMI comes earlier then official installer download page?

Comment: It should be fine to use the 9.0-9.3 template that uses 9.0-9.3 server. We created the AMI for a specific customer. It should be fine for you to use the 9.0-9.3 CF template.